# Stop sharepoint from reformatting html

Tags: url, hyperlink, encoding

I have a site page where I am trying to add a link to a particular calendar in outlook web access.

The URL is

`https://exchange.server.com/owa/sharedcalendaruser@mydomain.com/?cmd=contents&module=Calendar&view=monthly`

Sharepoint however urlencodes it, so the @ sign changes into %40.  Exchange doesn't like that, so the URL doesn't work.

How can I make sharepoint keep the link the way I enter it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A content editor web part can load the source HTML from a file and doesn't reformat it.

Store the HTML in a file called "calendarhtml.txt", or something meaningful, and point the cewp to that.

Comment: It seems even if you just add the link to a content editor web part, sharepoint doesn't reformat it.  So no need to load it from a file.  Just put the link in a content editor part instead of directly on the page.

Answer (score 5):

I have had good luck placing links in Web Part Pages Content Editors with javascript when I don't want SharePoint to change a relative URL to an Absolute. Maybe that will work.

```
<A title="A Test" href="javascript:window.location.href('http://myaddresshere.com/tech/@234?i=whatever')">My Link</A>.  See if that works
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem whereby a comma in a link was being automatically encoded to %2c.

I created a TinyUrl (which contains nothing for Sharepoint to encode) for the original link and use the TinyUrl on the Sharepoint site.

Sharepoint now links the person off to the TinyUrl which then redirects them the original link complete with it's unencoded comma.